# Determine profit factor (or percent) for kits/assemblies (sales price/(sum of qty * member_cost) in NetSuite saved search

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite I have a kit that has 2 member items. Within a saved search, I need to divide the base price by the sum of the kits components.

So the kit's price is $10
 compA is .50 and qty 2
 compB is $1 and qyt 1

my profit factor is 10/((.5*2)+1*1))=5. So my profit is 5 times my cost. I've got the saved search that gives me the denominator and it is `NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost})*{memberquantity}`
I look for average cost and if none, I use cost then times member quantity. I can then sum that with a summary function but how then, do I divide this in my base price because base price would need to be group or average but the cost is summed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just a small nitpick on your calculation/terminology.  In the example you gave (10/2=5) that shows that your *sales* value is 5 times your cost, not your profit.  Your profit would be (10-2)/2=4 times your cost.  It's similar to the often seen error of confusing margin and markup.

To answer your question: you will need to make it a summary search, grouped by item.  So item name or id can have the summary type Group.  To get the calculation you are trying to make, you would need to choose a summary type of Minimum, and include the actual summary inside the formula:

```
min({price}) / sum(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost}) * {memberquantity})
```

To get the margin, follow the same steps, but use the following formula:

```
(min({price}) - sum(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost}) * {memberquantity})) / min({price})
```

And, finally, for the markup:

```
(min({price}) - sum(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost}) * {memberquantity})) / sum(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost}) * {memberquantity})
```

Comment: Yes, I agree on the terminology. I was trying to keep it simple. Your solution worked well. Here is my actual formula in the netsuite saved search:

Answer (score 0):

Using @krypton as the starting point, here is the final formula for NetSuite

```
( (min/* comment */{price} OVER(PARTITION BY {name} ORDER BY {name}))-(CASE WHEN {type}='Inventory Item' THEN (sum/* comment */(NVL({averagecost},{cost})) OVER(PARTITION BY {name} ORDER BY {name})) ELSE (sum/* comment */(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost})*{memberquantity}) OVER(PARTITION BY {name} ORDER BY {name})) END))/(CASE WHEN {type}='Inventory Item' THEN (sum/* comment */(NVL({averagecost},{cost})) OVER(PARTITION BY {name} ORDER BY {name})) ELSE (sum/* comment */(NVL({memberitem.averagecost},{memberitem.cost})*{memberquantity}) OVER(PARTITION BY {name} ORDER BY {name})) END)
```